# C# Interop, Library Not Found

Tags: c#, c++, interop

I'm planning on moving the core of my licensing system to C++, but I'd still prefer a .NET front end for designing. In any case, I just finished reading up on interop functional, and decided to put it to the test. The thing is, it works just dandy on my end, but not for any other users. I let two friends test a small program on their PCs, and they're getting "Unable to load 'xxx.dll'. The specified module could not be found."

I have the C# program reading for the library within the same path as the program itself, so the error doesn't make any sense. As explained, it's working just fine for me.

C# Code,

```
[DllImport("GuardImports.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
public static extern string Gz_GetSystemKey();
```

I can't set a dynamic path, because DDLImport only takes constant variables. I wanted to try something like,

```
private const string loc = Application.StartupPath + "/xxx.dll";
```

But it obviously won't work, because the string isn't constant. The program can be downloaded here (http://neetcloud.us/MqMIXc) if anyone's interested, nothing special at all. The program just receives a hashed string from the lib, and displays it in a message box.

Comment: Is the GuardImports.dll file in your folder where you run your program, but not in that folder for your friends?

Comment: I've given them the lib with the program, and they have it in the same path.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps a 32-bit vs. 64-bit dependency? Or the dll is dependent on some other dll you have on your PC and your friends don't - check that with the Depends.exe utility. Isn't there a hex error code associated with the error, perhaps in the system event log?

Comment: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E', it literally isn't finding the library.

Comment: Try Googling that hex code - there are lots of possibilities, some of them very non-obvious.

Comment: If your dll can't find something it depends on, it will throw the 0x8007007E error and the error will be propagated up to your c# application. So it may be one of your dll's dependencies.

Comment: I'm only using the stdio & windows header files, as explained, nothing fancy. I was just playing around with interop functional.

Comment: The C++ dll is maybe looking for the C++ runtime routines. They are installed as part of Visual Studio, so they may not be present if your friends do not have Visual Studio installed. The C++ runtime can be downloaded and installed, it's a free download at Microsoft - but only for Release builds. Debug builds require the Debug C++ runtime, which is only part of Visual Studio, and Microsoft says no redistribution.

Comment: They have MS Redistributable 2010 and 12 installed, with .NET frameworks 4.5.

Comment: Going to go at it for another hour, if I can't get anything going, I'll just use a managed wrapper.

Comment: But is the C++ dll built for Debug or Release?

Comment: Debugged, I tried a release and it crashed my program. I guess I know what the source of the problem is now. Though I'm dumbfounded as to what may be causing it.

Comment: Like I said, you can't run a C++ dll built for Debug on a PC that does not have Visual Studio installed, so I think that's the reason your friends are getting the  0x8007007E error. As for your new problem with your program crashing when you build the C++ dll for Release, you should probably post a new question and provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

As per the discussion in the comments, it seems probable that your problem is that your C++ DLL was built for Debug, and that can't be run on a PC that does not have Visual Studio installed. Or maybe it can, but Microsoft has various demands, and says that in general you can't do it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985618.aspx

Answer (score 0):

After a very, very long night, I've debugged the problem. The issue standing, was that I hadn't defined my exports in the preprocessor definitions. All is working accordingly now. Thank you to those who took the time to hand me support.